# Can a static function in a trait call another static function in same trait?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits

Can a static function in a trait call another static function in same trait?
Suppose I have a trait below:

```
trait Test {
    fn prt() {
        println!("ok");
    }

    fn test() {
        Test::prt();
    }
}
```

That doesn't work. Code just can't compile here.

Also, there is no type for me to use fully qualified syntax like `<T as Test>::Test`. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Use `Self` to refer to the type that is implementing the trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a trait definition, you can use `Self` to refer to the type which implements the trait. For you, that would look like:

```
trait Test {
    fn prt() {
        println!("ok");
    }

    fn test() {
        Self::prt();
    }
}
```

There really is no such method as `Test::test` because its body is always defined by implementations of the trait. It just so happens that implementors will get that body by default if they don't provide their own.